# sshfs is mounting filesystems as another user

Tags: mount, permissions, users, sshfs

So I am trying to mount a folder from another computer in my LAN, and I am able to ssh without any issues. But, I am unable to make any changes when I access the mounted folder.

This is what I have done so far:

Install:

```
$sudo apt-get install sshfs
$sudo modprobe fuse
$sudo adduser <username> fuse
$sudo chown root:fuse /dev/fuse
$sudo chmod +x /dev/fuse
$mkdir ~/remoteserv
```

And when I access the remote folder via sshfs:

```
$sshfs -o idmap=user <username>@<ipaddress>:/home/user ~/remoteserv
```

The output of becomes:

```
$~/remoteserv$ ls -l
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 <notmyusername> <notmyusername> 4096 2012-04-13 21:54 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 1 <notmyusername> <notmyusername> 4096 2012-04-10 13:05 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 1 <notmyusername> <notmyusername> 4096 2012-04-17 19:06 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 1 <notmyusername> <notmyusername> 4096 2012-04-13 21:55 Music
drwxr-xr-x 1 <notmyusername> <notmyusername> 4096 2012-04-03 15:07 Pictures
... more of the same
```

I am unable to access any of the files properly because sshfs is mounting the files under my wife's username! I have no idea why, and I feel like I have made a large mistake somewhere. Is there some configuration file which I need to tweak somewhere? I can't seem to find anything on the manpage :/

I even tried an -o allow_other option when I mounted, but it still mounted it under my wife's username! What is going on?

Comment: This thread is quite old, but: did the answer below help you?

Comment: @rexford Wow, I don't even remember what I ended up doing this was so long ago. I think I ended up using a python SimpleHTTPServer like this https://mohitishere.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/instant-lan-file-sharing-with-python-simplehttpserver/

In the desired directory:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Then visit : http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 27):

It's worth a try to explicitly set the UID/GID. This could be done, for example, using the sshfs options:

```
uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)
```

or

```
uid=$(id -u someuser),gid=$(id -g somegroup)
```

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#Secure_user_access for more details.

Comment: This does not seem to match what the documentation says, neither does it work for me. -o idmap=username leads to an error and according to the docs, idmap can only be "none", "user" or "file" anyway. (on the other hand, the uid= and gid= options do have the desired effect when used alone)

Comment: @Nobody: Seems you're right - i can't remember if it worked as described over four years ago. TY for your comment!

Comment: Thanks. This is also related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/why-does-root-get-permission-denied-when-accessing-fuse-directory (maybe even a cross site duplicate)

Comment: In my case sshfs was using a readonly user for cockpit (1001:1001). I could have get compromised… Do we have any idea on why sshfs behave this way ?

Answer (score 11):

The complete command is

```
sshfs \
-o uid=`id -u username` \
-o gid=`id -g username` \
-o allow_other \
target_user@target.server:/target/folder \
/local/folder
```

it maps username's user_id and group_id to the mountpoint (so the mountpoint looks like that user's own).
The `allow_other` allows others to use this mountpoint which is good if the root mounts the folder for someone else.

Alternatively you can use `-o allow_root` to let root there too.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  Who are you replying to?  Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  Please try to compose your answers in a way that it answers the question without needing to read another post.

Comment: This worked for me and is really just a clearer and more complete version of the answer from tohuwawohu that I didn't understand at first.

Comment: This almost worked. I get the files/directories in the mount folder mapped to my user, but still get a permission denied when trying to create a file...

Comment: @borizzzzz maybe the target_user can not create file on the target.server in /target/folder