# Unable to create/edit/delete remote files after mounting them locally with SSHFS

Tags: server, 20.04, permissions, ssh, sshfs

I have a basic server set-up using a RaspberryPI, Ubuntu server 20.04, and Nginx. Using ssh, I can edit the files directly in the terminal, but that becomes sloppy, so I am looking for a more elegant way. Therefore - SSHFS.

Actions:

- Mounting the remote volume **/var/www/html** to a local folder **~/Work/Server**.
- Opening my text editor and trying to modify and save a file.

Problem:

- I receive the error **Unable to save file: Permission denied**

Trying to solve:

- used `sshfs -o allow_other` - Same result
- user `sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions` - Same result

Solution: ???

The volume mounts with no errors, I can open and view the files. The group owner of the remote /var/www is www-data, and the user I am connecting as is part of this group.

What am I missing and how can I make this configuration to actually work?

Comment: The website files are usually owned by `www-data` but readable by the group (not writable). The limit might be coming form the server side. Mount as `www-data` or change permissions.

Comment: Mounting as www-data will have any effect? From my understanding the sistem cares less about the names but for pid/guid's instead. I will consider changing permissions to 744 tho.

Comment: Yes UID/GID is more relevant, what I meant is, group membership is not the key, as write permissions are given to the file owner only, not the group. At least usually in `/var/www`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! :)

Comment: Sorry - but there seem to be misunderstandings. Please check the proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK a few basics, as we ran into misunderstandings:

1. The first level of permissions comes from the remote server: here files in `/var/www` are owned by `www-data` and group is set to the same.
2. By default only the owner has write access there, while the group is read-only. Thus mounting as your remoter user does not have the desired effect, as he is group member only and not `www-data` itself.
3. Best not to change ownership of `/var/www` as you did - this may break a few things. E.g. users would not be able to upload files to the server as `nginx` is ran by `www-data` and thus writes would be done as this user.

**So how to manage your problem?**

I believe the most secure way would be to mount it as user `www-data`. Let's go the safe route and use key-based logins only, as well as try to restrict access too the very part we need only. I'll be detailed so other users may profit as well.

Definitions:

- client - your PC at home
- server - the website server with the directory you want to mount
- `www-data` - the user www-data on the server
- `dan` - your local user on your client

Prerequisite: `root`-rights on server

**1) If not existing, create a keypair for `dan` on your client**

```
   ssh-keygen
```

Just go with no password. You now should now have the files `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in `~/.ssh` - If you are not familiar with passwordless ssh, there is plenty of information out there.

**2) Make `www-data` accept `dan`'s public key for logins**

`www-data` has `/var/www` as home directory. In some cases you might want to make this directory browseable. In general you would not want to put the `authorized_keys`-file (which is a list of accepted public keys for `ssh`-logins) there despite the `home` of a user being the standard location. Let's go for a dedicated place then; best in `/etc`.

On the server: Create a file `/etc/www/ssh/authorized_keys` (plus parent directories). Change ownership of file AND parent directory to `www-data`, as well as adapt permissions. This is necessary as `ssh` only accepts an `authorized_keys` file with specific permissions on the file and parent directory and ownership by the related user:

```
   chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/www/ssh
   chmod 700 /etc/www/ssh
   chmod 600 /etc/www/ssh/authorized_keys
```

Leave ownership of `/etc/www` with `root`

Now copy the content of `dan`'s public key (on client `/home/dan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` .... **pub!**, the other one is your secret file and never to be shared) to this file. Make sure the entry is on one line (sometimes copying may introduce newlines). Should look similar to this:

```
  cat /etc/www/ssh/authorized_keys
  ssh-rsa VERY+long+KEY+from+NUMBERS+and+LETTERS+covering+SEVERAL+lines dan@client
```

**3) Adapt `ssh`-server for this type of connection**

`www-data` has no shell for security reasons (see `/usr/sbin/nologin` from `grep www /etc/passwd`). We therefore need to adapt the `ssh`-server settings to still allow mounting directories. For security reasons, let's also change the root directory, so `www-data` via `ssh` may not escape outside `/var/www`, and enforce public key authentication, as well as deactivated interactively sending commands. After all a webserver sees the internet - hackers love this.

On the server: At the END of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add these lines. Note that match blocks never end until the next match block. Also note that `/var/www` must be owned by `root` (as is default) for the `ChrootDirectory` command to work.

```
Match User www-data
    AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/www/ssh/authorized_keys
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

(Sources: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#Chrooting) , [ssh without shell](https://bondarenko.xyz/sshfs.html) , [defining authorized keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558495/how-can-i-provide-the-authorized-keys-path-in-sshd-that-allows-normal-users-sys))

Reload the config via `systemctl reload ssh`.

**4. All done**

Do the `sshfs`-mount as desired on the client

```
sshfs www-data@server:/html /homa/dan/WorkServer
```

Note that with the changed root directory, `/var/www/html` becomes `/hmtl` only as `/var/www` is now the root directory.

**5. Additional hardening**

If applicable: you are doing this in your workplace LAN only? Deny `ssh`-access to `www-data` globally and grant it on the network only. Before the match block in `sshd_config`:

```
 DenyUsers www-data
```

and put the work LAN (e.g. 192.168. block) in the match criteria:

```
 Match User www-data Address 192.168.
```

Comment: This is like the holy grail of remote connections! Haven't got the chance to put it in play but as soon as I do I will come back and accept / comment along this fine answer. Thank you!

Comment: Worked like a charm. **Thank you for taking the time to respond and for adding the documentation for all this information** - it seems harder to find what you need when you don't really know what you are looking for.

A single issue tho - `700 / 600 permissions` won't work, making the ssh directory unreachable. Instead, I have used `744 and 644 respectively` to be able to `cd` in the dir and `nano` the authorized_keys file. I have switched back to `700 / 600 permissions` afterward.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding
-o uid=999
to the
sudo sshfs....
command fixed it where 999 is the uid of the remote user that owns the files.

You can find the remote uid by logging into the remote via regular SSH and running id -u

This is a less automated take on the answers at [sshfs is mounting filesystems as another user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123215/sshfs-is-mounting-filesystems-as-another-user)

Answer (score -1):

Update - (Possible) Fix:

I followed the tip of [@Fiximan](https://askubuntu.com/users/431425/fiximan) and I have **mounted the volume in the local /var/www/html** which is owned by www-data, just as is on the remote.

Additionally, I have changed the remote owner of /var/www/html to the user that I am logging in as (user which is part of the www-data group).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstandings. But this is not a good solution for several reasons. Please check my answer.